# How create a pathfinding with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, path-finding

Currently in the last year of high school I want to make a video game in python with pygame. However I have a problem: how to make the monsters (sprite) go from point A to point B by following my road.
I do not have any code to show because I do not know how to do it.

I hope you can help me <3
[My map (in brown the road)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV33L.jpg)
There is the try code

```
class Niveau_1_Monstres(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image,position):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = position
        self.direction = 'droite' ## La direction

    def update(self):
        pygame.time.delay(5)#mettre 100
        #définition de la direction
        if self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape1) == True:
            self.direction = 'haut'
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape2) == True:
            self.direction = 'droite'   
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape3) == True:
            self.direction = 'bas'     
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape4) == True:
            self.direction = 'droite'      
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape5) == True:
            self.direction = 'haut'    
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape6) == True:
            self.direction = 'droite' 
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape7) == True:
            self.direction = 'bas'
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape8) == True:
            self.direction = 'gauche'   
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape9) == True:
            self.direction = 'haut' 
        elif self.rect.colliderect(lv1.rectetape10) == True:
            self.direction = 'gauche'  

        #Mouvelent en fonction de la direction
        if self.direction == 'haut':
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y-1
        elif self.direction == 'bas':
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y+1
        elif self.direction == 'gauche':
            self.rect.x = self.rect.x-1
        elif self.direction == 'droite':
            self.rect.x = self.rect.x+1
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO. Unfortunately that sort of question is off-topic on the site (it is too broad, there are so many ways to do it!). I recommend you start with a tutorial, or google for something like "pygame A* pathfinding" etc. Here is one: https://www.pygame.org/project/767

Comment: read [ask].......................

Answer (score 0):

The road can be visualized as a list of lines joined together. All you need to do is

a) Store the starting and ending coordinates of each line

```
[ [(x11, y11), (x12, y12)], [(x21, y21), (x22, y22)], ... ]
```

b) Make your sprite move sequentially from each starting coordinate to the final one. Some simple logic in the while loop will do it. You can base your code off this [basic example](http:////invpy.com/catanimation.py).

Comment: I've try this solution but every time I add a sprite the game idle because he must do all the calculations.

Comment: Could you include the part of your code that does these calculations?